# Can I use Razor script inside content on Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, orchardcms

Is it possible to use Razor script inside content in Orchard? By content I mean the text one enters with admin site when editing content.

If not possible, is there a way to handle this? I'd like to process some text and use Script.Include to add js specific to certain pages.

Comment: No that is not possible. When editing content it is stored and read as HTML/raw, not as server side code. You can achieve something similar though by creating a View editor instead of using content editor.

Comment: It is possible. Take a look at Orchard.Templates, it's in the core. You can create Orchard shapes via a backend editor, which can contain razor code